# Extracting a random sample from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

This is sample data

```
data = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, 
       {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}, {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6}}
```

My actual data contains 10000 sub-lists with 6 elements.

How can I create a new list `data2` containing a sample of `N` random six-lets of the initial list?

In our MWE let's take `N = 3`.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `RandomSample[data, 3]` I believe you have to practice your docs-fu

Comment: @belisariushassettled With your suggestion is there a chance a six-let to appear twice or more times in the new list, or all `N` are different?

Comment: Dude, don't ask those things. Go to the docs and check them out

Comment: @belisariushassettled You are right! Some times I so lazy...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood well, you do not want to create those sample elements out of the elements of sublists. With this assumption the answer is

```
n=3;
data2=RandomChoice[data, n]
```

Example output:

```
{{3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}}
```

If you would like to randomly select out of all elements it would be:

```
data2=RandomChoice[Flatten@data, {n, 6}]
```

Example output:

```
{{2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 1}, {6, 1, 5, 2, 1, 6}, {3, 3, 6, 2, 2, 1}}
```

EDIT: If no elements are supposed to repeat then it would be:

```
data2=RandomSample[data, n]
```

Example output:

```
{{2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3}}
```

Comment: No, I want `N` random six-lets from the initial data. But all of them should be different. In your suggestion the six-let (2,2,2,2,2,2) appears twice!

Comment: The last one is really what I want!